# How to add a list to a list of list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to combine two lists.  This is what i have

```
l1 = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [10, 11, 12]]
l2 = [6,7,8]
```

This is what I have tried this

```
def merge(list1, list2):
    merged_list = [(list1[i], list2[i]) for i in range(0, len(list1))]
    return merged_list
```

This produces something close

```
l3 = merge(l1,l2)
[([1, 2, 3], 6), ([3, 4, 5], 7), ([10, 11, 12], 8)]
```

But this is what I want

```
l3 = [1,2,3,6], [3,4,5,7], [10,11,12,8]
```

How do i merge the two lists to get the list of list above?

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip` with `+` operator to append

**Ex:**

```
l1 = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [10, 11, 12]]
l2 = [6,7,8]


def merge(list1, list2):
    return [i + [v] for i, v in zip(list1, list2)]
print( merge(l1,l2))
# --> [[1, 2, 3, 6], [3, 4, 5, 7], [10, 11, 12, 8]]
```

Comment: Mark this answer if so.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest making a copy of l1 before proceeding

```
l1 = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [10, 11, 12]]
l2 = [6,7,8]
for i, j in zip(l1,l2):
    i.append(j)
print(l1)
```

**Output:**

[[1, 2, 3, 6], [3, 4, 5, 7], [10, 11, 12, 8]]

Answer (score 1):

With a simple list of comprehension:

```
l1 = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [10, 11, 12]]
l2 = [6,7,8]

[l1[idx] + [val] for idx, val in enumerate(l2)]
```

**Ouptut**

```
[[1, 2, 3, 6], [3, 4, 5, 7], [10, 11, 12, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(l1)):
    l1[i].append(l2[i])
```

Simply add the `ith` element of l2 in `ith` list of l1. This gives the output

```
[[1, 2, 3, 6], [3, 4, 5, 7], [10, 11, 12, 8]]
```